# How can I get the source code of the sound drivers in ubuntu?

Tags: sound, kernel, software-sources

I have dual boot windows and ubuntu. Ubuntu can correctly detect and play my ESS 1969 sound card. So, I was thinking of the source code of ubuntu driver so that I can compile and run it on my windows 7 for sound?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the driver is freely available from several places, including in the Ubuntu archive itself.

However, you cannot simply take that source code and compile it on Windows, expecting to have a driver for your Windows platform. The open source driver in the Linux kernel is a driver for Linux only, and not for other operating systems.

You will need to get the driver for your sound card for Windows 7, from the manufacturer of your sound card.